# linker error when using Qt and Boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, boost, linker-errors

When I am using Qt (v4.7.4) and Boost (tried v1.47 and v1.48) together in my c++ project, I get a linker error caused by a class that includes `<boost\filesystem.hpp>`. I just set up Qt and before the code was working without any problems.

This is error message:

> ...obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::codecvt const * & __cdecl boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet(void)" (?wchar_t_codecvt_facet@path@filesystem3@boost@@CAAAPBV?$codecvt@GDH@std@@XZ)
>
> ...obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem3::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem3@boost@@YAXPBD0AAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@GDH@5@@Z)
>
> ...obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem3::path_traits::dispatch(class boost::filesystem3::directory_entry const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)" (?dispatch@path_traits@filesystem3@boost@@YAXABVdirectory_entry@23@AAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@GDH@6@@Z)
>
> ...obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem3::path_traits::convert(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &,class std::codecvt const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem3@boost@@YAXPBG0AAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@GDH@5@@Z)
>
> ...exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/68257) I found someone having this problem coming to this conclusion:

> this really is a Qt issue. Using wchar_t as a native type you have to
>   recompile Qt using the same compiler switch. There even is a bug in the
>   tracker: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9617
>
> In general, you will have to be very careful and do not mix wchar_t
>   compiler settings in your projects as they will become incompatible.

So I recompiled Qt setting `/Zc:wchar_t`, but it didn't show any effect. I still get the same error.

Comment: have you compiled boost? I'm not too familiar with what exactly needs building but some libraries do.

Comment: yes. I've compiled it for Visual Studio 2010 using `b2.exe` if I remember correctly.

Comment: might it be necessary to recompile the whole boost library? I don't remember the exact build configuration, but I definitely didn't change `treat wchar_t as build-in type` property when I was compiling boost.

Comment: Could you include at least line from your compiler output? Perhaps `cl ...`? It sounds to me like your `/Zc:wchar_t` didn't take for some reason. Your compiler output would show that.

Comment: Is this information stored somewhere? As compiling takes a few hours, I wouldn't want to recompile unless necessary. Anyway, this is how I set wchar_t:  `QMAKE_CFLAGS = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t`. This is the file edited: `$(BOOST)\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010\qmake.conf`. I had a look at `$(BOOST)\.qmake.cache` and noticed that `QMAKESPEC` points to the same directory where I made the changed.

Comment: Could you show me an example how to use `cl` to get the information you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant when you compile the program that is causing the problem. The "Compile Output" window shows the commands used to compile the program. You should have something like `cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -WX ... blah ... blah ... blah`

Comment: thanks, you were right. I forgot to set /Zc:wchar_t in my project. Well, if post an answer, you can have the bounty ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but it sounds like your `-Zc:wchar_t` didn't "stick." We had to do the same thing to make Qt happy with Google Breakpad and the ICU library. We changed    the `/Zc:wchar_t` setting in `(QT_SOURCE)\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008\qmake.conf` and compiled Qt from source, and after that everything works.

When you build your project that uses Qt and Boost, you should see this option in the compiler output. Something like:

```
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t ... (etc.)
```

If you've already build Qt without this option, you may have to do a `make confclean` first to ensure everything *really* gets rebuilt with the new settings.

It sounds like [-Zc:wchar_t will be the default in Qt 5](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9617).

Answer (score 2):

Using boost-1.49, Qt 4.4 and VS2005 had the same problem. Going to project properties, then setting "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Treat wchar_t as Built-in Type" to "Yes" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Qt probably changed the tipology of your program with regards the configuration of the runtime: consequently, the boost library you use (filesystem), that come in many configuration accessed by naming convention - connot be found.

For instance, multithread runtimes require *mt* somewhere in library name (I hope I remember well, but anyway see the docs where details are fully documented). This naming is fairly transparent to the programmer, due to pragmas that boost programmers appropriately used to ease the library usage under different compilers.

You should miss the non-wchar filesystem.lib. When I used Windows, I used boost Jam to interface with Visual C++ (may be that goes back to the past *millenium*!). I hope it's still usable.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I added `boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.lib`to my dependencies and `$(BOOST)\stage\lib`to the directories. The paths are definitely fine, I've copied them from another project, which is compiling without errors. I've checked the `runtime library` property of all my sheets, and they are all set to `multithreaded DLL (/MD)`, just as in my other project. Since these settings are the same I'd assume it cannot be a naming problem, or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I improperly referred to multithread, and hence _mt_, you clearly explained  that was a change in character type. I hope I can verify my hipotesis in boost, appropriate technical detail.